# Resolving build dependencies between environments in multi-stage Docker file

Tags: docker, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, devspace

This is my dilemma:

- Implemented [layer caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#docker-images) in our Azure DevOps Pipelines using [multi-stage `Dockerfiles`](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#use-multi-stage-builds) (e.g., `development:latest` is a dependency of the `unit-test` and `integration-test` stages).
- To get this to work properly, I had to add image tags to images that are a dependency of another stage, otherwise layer caching would ignore it and rebuild the stage. ADO won't let you build an image without a tag and if you don't provide one it just uses `$(Build.BuildId)` or something.
- Adding the tags is now breaking the local dev environments using `devspace` because now it sees the `development` stage has a dependency like `COPY --from=builder-base:latest` and tries to pull it from a remote repo instead of just building it locally. Changing it to `COPY --from=builder-base` fixes the issue, but then layer caching quits working.

Here is my `Dockerfile`...

```
# creating a python base with shared environment variables
FROM python:3.9-slim as python-base
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    POETRY_HOME="/opt/poetry" \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true \
    POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    PYSETUP_PATH="/opt/pysetup" \
    VENV_PATH="/opt/pysetup/.venv"

ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:$VENV_PATH/bin:$PATH"
# triggering a recache in the pipelines

# builder-base is used to build dependencies
FROM python-base as builder-base
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        curl \
        build-essential 
        
# Install Poetry - respects $POETRY_VERSION & $POETRY_HOME
ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.4.1 GET_POETRY_IGNORE_DEPRECATION=1
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -

# We copy our Python requirements here to cache them
# and install on ly runtime deps using poetry
WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH
COPY ./poetry.lock ./pyproject.toml ./
RUN poetry install --no-dev     


# 'development' stage installs all dev deps and can be used to develop code.
# For example using docker-compose to mount local volume under /app
FROM python-base as development

# Copying poetry and venv into image
COPY --from=builder-base:latest $POETRY_HOME $POETRY_HOME
COPY --from=builder-base:latest $PYSETUP_PATH $PYSETUP_PATH

# Copying in our entrypoint
# COPY ./docker/docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x . /opt/pysetup/.venv/bin/activate

# venv already has runtime deps installed we get a quicker install
WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH
RUN poetry install
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000 5672
CMD [ "python", "src/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:5000"]


# 'unit-tests' stage runs our unit tests with unittest and coverage.   
FROM development:latest AS unit-tests
ENV CI=True
RUN coverage run --omit='src/manage.py,src/config/*,*/.venv/*,*/*__init__.py,*/tests.py,*/admin.py' src/manage.py test src --tag=ut && \
    coverage report


# # 'integration-tests' stage runs our integration tests with unittest and coverage.  
FROM development:latest AS integration-tests
ENV CI=True
RUN coverage run --omit='src/manage.py,src/config/*,*/.venv/*,*/*__init__.py,*/tests.py,*/admin.py' src/manage.py test src --tag=it && \
    coverage report


# 'production' stage uses the clean 'python-base' stage and copies
# in only our runtime deps that were installed in the 'builder-base'
FROM python-base as production
COPY --from=builder-base:latest $VENV_PATH $VENV_PATH
RUN chmod +x . /opt/pysetup/.venv/bin/activate
COPY ./src /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", ":5000", "--log-level", "info", "config.wsgi:application", "-t", "600", "-w", "4"]
```

In particular these lines...

```
...
# Copying poetry and venv into image
COPY --from=builder-base:latest $POETRY_HOME $POETRY_HOME
COPY --from=builder-base:latest $PYSETUP_PATH $PYSETUP_PATH
...
```

Again, changing it to the following fixes local dev, but breaks layer caching in the pipelines:

```
...
# Copying poetry and venv into image
COPY --from=builder-base $POETRY_HOME $POETRY_HOME
COPY --from=builder-base $PYSETUP_PATH $PYSETUP_PATH
...
```

The fix, I believe, would need to be in the `Dockerfile`. Not quite sure how it can be setup to accommodate both use cases without making a `Dockerfile.dev` which I'm trying to avoid. Suggestions?

---

Case where layer caching does not work:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim as python-base
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    POETRY_HOME="/opt/poetry" \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true \
    POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    PYSETUP_PATH="/opt/pysetup" \
    VENV_PATH="/opt/pysetup/.venv"

ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:$VENV_PATH/bin:$PATH"


FROM python-base as builder-base
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        curl \
        build-essential 
...


FROM python-base as development

# Copying poetry and venv into image
COPY --from=builder-base $POETRY_HOME $POETRY_HOME
COPY --from=builder-base $PYSETUP_PATH $PYSETUP_PATH
...
```

Here's my oversimplified `pipeline.yaml`:

```
# Read in the base variable template
variables:
  dockerfilePath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
  cacheBuster: 1 #change as need to create a new cache

pool:
  vmIMage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: BuildBase
  jobs:
  - job: BuildBase
    steps:
    - task: Cache@2
      inputs: 
        key: 'docker | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(cacheBuster)'
        path: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/docker
    - task: Docker@2
      inputs:
        command: build
        repository: builder-base
        dockerfile: $(dockerFilePath)/api/docker/Dockerfile
        buildContext: $(dockerFilePath)/api
        arguments: |
          --target builder-base
      env:
        DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
    - bash: |
        docker images
        mkdir -p $(Pipeline.Workspace)/docker
        docker save -o $(Pipeline.Workspace)/docker/api.tar builder-base

- stage: BuildDev
  dependsOn:
  - BuildBase
  jobs:
  - job: BuildBase
    steps:
    - task: Cache@2
      displayName: Creating cache...
      inputs: 
        key: 'docker | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(cacheBuster)'
        path: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/docker    
    - script: |
        ls -l $(Pipeline.Workspace)/docker/
        docker load -i $(Pipeline.Workspace)/docker/api.tar
        docker images
    - task: Docker@2
      inputs:
        command: build
        repository: development
        dockerfile: $(dockerFilePath)/api/docker/Dockerfile
        buildContext: $(dockerFilePath)/api
        arguments: |
          --cache-from builder-base
          --target development
      env:
        DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
```

- Currently, when it gets to `docker save` it will fail because a tag wasn't specified in the preceding build task.
- Due to it not being specified in that task, ADO just uses `$(Build.BuildId)` by default.
- In order for `docker save` to work, it needs the tag so I'll just `latest` for simplicity.

```
...
    - task: Docker@2
      inputs:
        command: build
        repository: builder-base
        dockerfile: $(dockerFilePath)/api/docker/Dockerfile
        buildContext: $(dockerFilePath)/api
        arguments: |
          --target builder-base
        tags: |
          latest
      env:
        DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
    - bash: |
        docker images
        mkdir -p $(Pipeline.Workspace)/docker
        docker save -o $(Pipeline.Workspace)/docker/api.tar builder-base:latest
...
```

Now `docker save` works and in the subsequent stage it is loaded:

```
Starting: CmdLine
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.212.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/1efef7d5-af4c-4705-9d59-2d38371a3caa.sh
total 806740
-rw------- 1 vsts docker 826097152 Jun 21 21:42 api.tar
Loaded image: builder-base:latest
REPOSITORY       TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED              SIZE
builder-base     latest      c5ae5e84153f   About a minute ago   803MB
```

When it gets to building the `development` image which depends on `builder-base`, it sees the cache but ignores it and continues to the build the stage anyway.

```
#18 importing cache manifest from builder-base
#18 sha256:db249d01eb28b6ad07804991ed483e6c4b76b050c42dd6a446b98270f592ab8b
#18 DONE 0.0s

#8 [internal] load build context
#8 sha256:b04f2e0c5898df2da834f79948847ffaa3260437bebc394051e3aa07d9d323a8
#8 transferring context: 870.99kB 0.0s done
#8 DONE 0.1s

#4 [python-base 1/1] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.9-slim
#4 sha256:f876c6f14c8c365d299789228d8a0c38ac92e17ea62116c830f5b7c6bc684e47
#4 DONE 0.1s

#5 [builder-base 1/5] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y         curl         build-essential
#5 sha256:9c96647f9ffa22c5b2b8b587ece6818721296b3927cc3757c843a52f122598d3
```

Try any of the variations in the `development` build stage and still the same results:

```
...
    - task: Docker@2
      inputs:
        command: build
        repository: development
        dockerfile: $(dockerFilePath)/api/docker/Dockerfile
        buildContext: $(dockerFilePath)/api
        arguments: |
          --cache-from builder-base:latest
          --target development
      env:
        DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
...
...
    - task: Docker@2
      inputs:
        command: build
        repository: development
        dockerfile: $(dockerFilePath)/api/docker/Dockerfile
        buildContext: $(dockerFilePath)/api
        arguments: |
          --cache-from builder-base
          --target development
        tags: |
          latest
      env:
        DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
...
```

Even tried `docker rmi builder-base:latest` to get rid of the tags altogether, but that just removes the image since there are no other tags.

Again, the only way I've been able to find to get it to load the cached image is adding the tags to the multi-stage `Dockerfile` which breaks dev.

If there is a fix, or if I have something not configured properly, I'd love to know. Otherwise, turning caching off for the time being seems to be the best option.

Comment: Multi-stage builds don't have tags – I would expect the intermediate stages to be labeled `FROM development` without an explicit tag.  I'd also expect, using the BuildKit backend, the builder would skip the various unused stages that don't affect the final image.  Can you cut down the example some, and describe a case where layer caching doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: @DavidMaze I added details on the layer cacheing not working. My `Dockerfile` originally had no tags in it for these stages. I didn't add them until it became apparent that ADO pipelines layer cacheing wouldn't work properly without them (explain above).